# manual colormap plot screws with ticklabels

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I want to manually create a colormap plot with pgfplots. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{scaled x ticks=false}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{0.96,0.742,0.29}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.32,0.738}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  map color/.code={\pgfmathparse{500 + 500*#1}\pgfplotscolormapdefinemappedcolor{\pgfmathresult}},
  meta/.style={map color=#1,minimum size=3em,fill=mapped color}
]
\begin{axis}[
    colormap={bluewhiteyellow}{color=(myyellow) color=(white) color=(myblue)},
    clip = false,
    colorbar,
    colormap name={bluewhiteyellow},
    x=3em,
    y=3em,
    xtick=data,
    ytick=data,
    ymin={[normalized]0},
    ymax={[normalized]9},
    xmin={[normalized]0},
    xmax={[normalized]27},
    enlarge x limits={abs=1.5em},
    enlarge y limits={abs=1.5em},
    point meta min=-1,
    point meta max=1,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={draw=none},
    minor tick num=1,
    symbolic x coords={cHq3,cHB,cHW,cHWB,cuBAbs,cuWAbs,cHDD,cHd,cHu,cHq1,cHe,cHl1,cHl3,cll1,cHG,cuGAbs,cG,cqd8,cqq1,cqq11,cqq3,cqq31,cqu1,cqu8,cuH,cud8,cuu,cuu1},
    symbolic y coords={ggHtopev3,ggHtopev2,ggHtopev1,cHl3cll1ev1,cHl1cHeev1,cHucHdcHq1ev1,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1,cHq3},
%    xticklabels={cHq3,cHB,cHW,cHWB,cuBAbs,cuWAbs,cHDD,cHd,cHu,cHq1,cHe,cHl1,cHl3,cll1,cHG,cuGAbs,cG,cqd8,cqq1,cqq11,cqq3,cqq31,cqu1,cqu8,cuH,cud8,cuu,cuu1},
%    yticklabels={ggHtopev3,ggHtopev2,ggHtopev1,cHl3cll1ev1,cHl1cHeev1,cHucHdcHq1ev1,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1,cHq3},
    axis on top,
    x tick label style={scale=1.5,anchor=north east,rotate=45},
    y tick label style={scale=1.5},
    colorbar style={y tick label style={scale=1.5}},
    tick style={draw=none}
 ]
\node [meta=1.0] at (axis cs:cHq3,cHq3){1.00};
\node [meta=0.5] at (axis cs:cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){0.50};
\node [meta=0.19] at (axis cs:cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2){0.19};
\node [meta=-0.84] at (axis cs:cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1){-0.84};
\node [meta=-0.08] at (axis cs:cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){-0.08};
\node [meta=-0.96] at (axis cs:cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2){-0.96};
\node [meta=-0.27] at (axis cs:cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1){-0.27};
\node [meta=0.86] at (axis cs:cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){0.86};
\node [meta=-0.2] at (axis cs:cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2){-0.20};
\node [meta=0.47] at (axis cs:cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1){0.47};
\node [meta=0.06] at (axis cs:cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){0.06};
\node [meta=0.02] at (axis cs:cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2){0.02};
\node [meta=-0.05] at (axis cs:cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1){-0.05};
\node [meta=0.03] at (axis cs:cuWAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){0.03};
\node [meta=-0.02] at (axis cs:cuWAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1){-0.02};
\node [meta=0.07] at (axis cs:cHDD,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3){0.07};
\node [meta=0.26] at (axis cs:cHd,cHucHdcHq1ev1){0.26};
\node [meta=-0.87] at (axis cs:cHu,cHucHdcHq1ev1){-0.87};
\node [meta=0.42] at (axis cs:cHq1,cHucHdcHq1ev1){0.42};
\node [meta=-0.62] at (axis cs:cHe,cHl1cHeev1){-0.62};
\node [meta=0.78] at (axis cs:cHl1,cHl1cHeev1){0.78};
\node [meta=0.87] at (axis cs:cHl3,cHl3cll1ev1){0.87};
\node [meta=-0.5] at (axis cs:cll1,cHl3cll1ev1){-0.50};
\node [meta=-0.03] at (axis cs:cHG,ggHtopev3){-0.03};
\node [meta=-0.03] at (axis cs:cHG,ggHtopev2){-0.03};
\node [meta=0.99] at (axis cs:cHG,ggHtopev1){0.99};
\node [meta=0.67] at (axis cs:cuGAbs,ggHtopev3){0.67};
\node [meta=0.73] at (axis cs:cuGAbs,ggHtopev2){0.73};
\node [meta=0.03] at (axis cs:cuGAbs,ggHtopev1){0.03};
\node [meta=0.29] at (axis cs:cG,ggHtopev3){0.29};
\node [meta=-0.18] at (axis cs:cG,ggHtopev2){-0.18};
\node [meta=0.03] at (axis cs:cqd8,ggHtopev3){0.03};
\node [meta=-0.04] at (axis cs:cqd8,ggHtopev2){-0.04};
\node [meta=0.04] at (axis cs:cqq1,ggHtopev3){0.04};
\node [meta=-0.03] at (axis cs:cqq1,ggHtopev2){-0.03};
\node [meta=0.25] at (axis cs:cqq11,ggHtopev3){0.25};
\node [meta=-0.23] at (axis cs:cqq11,ggHtopev2){-0.23};
\node [meta=0.05] at (axis cs:cqq3,ggHtopev3){0.05};
\node [meta=-0.05] at (axis cs:cqq3,ggHtopev2){-0.05};
\node [meta=0.55] at (axis cs:cqq31,ggHtopev3){0.55};
\node [meta=-0.54] at (axis cs:cqq31,ggHtopev2){-0.54};
\node [meta=0.01] at (axis cs:cqu1,ggHtopev3){0.01};
\node [meta=-0.01] at (axis cs:cqu1,ggHtopev2){-0.01};
\node [meta=0.16] at (axis cs:cqu8,ggHtopev3){0.16};
\node [meta=-0.15] at (axis cs:cqu8,ggHtopev2){-0.15};
\node [meta=0.1] at (axis cs:cuH,ggHtopev3){0.10};
\node [meta=0.06] at (axis cs:cuH,ggHtopev2){0.06};
\node [meta=0.03] at (axis cs:cud8,ggHtopev3){0.03};
\node [meta=-0.04] at (axis cs:cud8,ggHtopev2){-0.04};
\node [meta=0.02] at (axis cs:cuu,ggHtopev3){0.02};
\node [meta=-0.02] at (axis cs:cuu,ggHtopev2){-0.02};
\node [meta=0.26] at (axis cs:cuu1,ggHtopev3){0.26};
\node [meta=-0.24] at (axis cs:cuu1,ggHtopev2){-0.24};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, for reasons that I don't understand, uncommenting the `xticklabels` and `yticklabels` options (which should do absolutely nothing as far as I am concerned, as they at the moment contain the same text) shifts all the ticklabels by 1 unit. I find this highly confusing. How can this behavior be avoided?

Comment: Just having a quick look at it I also don't know why this is happening. But you can simply avoid this by adding an empty argument, i.e. just a comma as first entry, to the `ticklabels`.

Comment: Thanks!
I have the suspicion that the problem is related to the fact that the axis environment is empty. If I use the same axis environment, but use `\addplot` instead of manually writing the nodes, it works. That's quite mysterious to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found the cause of the label shift yet, I feel like it has something to do with the `normalized` option though. I'll look into it later.

In the meantime, I wanted to propose a slightly alternative code to yours, which by the way, doesn't have the same problem.

Instead of typing several `\node` commands, you can just do a single `\addplot ... coordinates` so you just need the coordinates themselves and the meta information. I added notes to the additions to explain what they do.

**Updates:**

- added colormap for text

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{0.96,0.742,0.29}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.1,0.32,0.738}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.17,
    colormap={bluewhiteyellow}{color=(myyellow) color=(white) color=(myblue)},%original
    colormap={mytext}{%
        % black:
        rgb(0000pt)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        rgb(1000pt)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        % black:
        rgb(1005pt)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        rgb(2000pt)=(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        % white
        rgb(2005pt)=(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        rgb(3000pt)=(1.0,1.0,1.0);
        },% a new colormap for the text
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    colormap name={bluewhiteyellow},% for the basic plotting, we use this colormap
    clip=false,
    colorbar,
    x=3em,
    y=3em,
    %xtick=data, % uncommenting these two will remove grid lines for y
    %ytick=data, % also, not needed
    ymin={[normalized]0},
    ymax={[normalized]9},
    xmin={[normalized]0},
    xmax={[normalized]27},
    enlarge x limits={abs=1.5em},
    enlarge y limits={abs=1.5em},
    point meta min=-1,
    point meta max=1,
    grid=both,
    major grid style={draw=none},
    minor tick num=1,
    symbolic x coords={cHq3,cHB,cHW,cHWB,cuBAbs,cuWAbs,cHDD,cHd,cHu,cHq1,cHe,cHl1,cHl3,cll1,cHG,cuGAbs,cG,cqd8,cqq1,cqq11,cqq3,cqq31,cqu1,cqu8,cuH,cud8,cuu,cuu1},
    symbolic y coords={ggHtopev3,ggHtopev2,ggHtopev1,cHl3cll1ev1,cHl1cHeev1,cHucHdcHq1ev1,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1,cHq3},
    %xticklabels={cHq3,cHB,cHW,cHWB,cuBAbs,cuWAbs,cHDD,cHd,cHu,cHq1,cHe,cHl1,cHl3,cll1,cHG,cuGAbs,cG,cqd8,cqq1,cqq11,cqq3,cqq31,cqu1,cqu8,cuH,cud8,cuu,cuu1},
    %yticklabels={ggHtopev3,ggHtopev2,ggHtopev1,cHl3cll1ev1,cHl1cHeev1,cHucHdcHq1ev1,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1,cHq3},
    axis on top,
    x tick label style={scale=1.5,anchor=north east,rotate=45},
    y tick label style={scale=1.5},
    colorbar style={y tick label style={scale=1.5}},
    tick style={draw=none},
    nodes near coords style={% style of the numbers inside marks
        anchor=center,
        font=\footnotesize,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2,
        color of colormap=\pgfplotspointmetatransformed of mytext% we use the new colormap for coloring the text dynamically
    },
    ]
    \addplot[
        only marks,
        mark=square*,
        scatter,
        mark size=1.5em,
        scatter src=explicit,% the color for the marks
        nodes near coords*,% the numbers on top
        ] 
        coordinates
        {
            (cHq3,cHq3) [1.00]
            (cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [0.50]
            (cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2) [0.19]
            (cHB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1) [-0.84]
            (cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [-0.08]
            (cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2) [-0.96]
            (cHW,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1) [-0.27]
            (cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [0.86]
            (cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2) [-0.20]
            (cHWB,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1) [0.47]
            (cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [0.06]
            (cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev2) [0.02]
            (cuBAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1) [-0.05]
            (cuWAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [0.03]
            (cuWAbs,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev1) [-0.02]
            (cHDD,cHWcHBcHWBcHDDcuWAbscuBAbsev3) [0.07]
            (cHd,cHucHdcHq1ev1) [0.26]
            (cHu,cHucHdcHq1ev1) [-0.87]
            (cHq1,cHucHdcHq1ev1) [0.42]
            (cHe,cHl1cHeev1) [-0.62]
            (cHl1,cHl1cHeev1) [0.78]
            (cHl3,cHl3cll1ev1) [0.87]
            (cll1,cHl3cll1ev1) [-0.50]
            (cHG,ggHtopev3) [-0.03]
            (cHG,ggHtopev2) [-0.03]
            (cHG,ggHtopev1) [0.99]
            (cuGAbs,ggHtopev3) [0.67]
            (cuGAbs,ggHtopev2) [0.73]
            (cuGAbs,ggHtopev1) [0.03]
            (cG,ggHtopev3) [0.29]
            (cG,ggHtopev2) [-0.18]
            (cqd8,ggHtopev3) [0.03]
            (cqd8,ggHtopev2) [-0.04]
            (cqq1,ggHtopev3) [0.04]
            (cqq1,ggHtopev2) [-0.03]
            (cqq11,ggHtopev3) [0.25]
            (cqq11,ggHtopev2) [-0.23]
            (cqq3,ggHtopev3) [0.05]
            (cqq3,ggHtopev2) [-0.05]
            (cqq31,ggHtopev3) [0.55]
            (cqq31,ggHtopev2) [-0.54]
            (cqu1,ggHtopev3) [0.01]
            (cqu1,ggHtopev2) [-0.01]
            (cqu8,ggHtopev3) [0.16]
            (cqu8,ggHtopev2) [-0.15]
            (cuH,ggHtopev3) [0.10]
            (cuH,ggHtopev2) [0.06]
            (cud8,ggHtopev3) [0.03]
            (cud8,ggHtopev2) [-0.04]
            (cuu,ggHtopev3) [0.02]
            (cuu,ggHtopev2) [-0.02]
            (cuu1,ggHtopev3) [0.26]
            (cuu1,ggHtopev2) [-0.24]
        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that looks really great, thanks so much! I don't think it's related to the normalized option, this I added after the problem was already there, but let me know you are able to figure it out. One reason I wanted to have individual nodes is to be able to change the font color to white whenever the value is above .9 to increase visibility. If you can add that to your solution, I'm sold!

Comment: @carsten Sure, I'll look into it :)

Comment: @carsten I still don't know why that bug happens. It might be some interference with the underlying code. Anyway, I have updated the code for making the text easier to read. Enjoy :)